# Scan a wifi network in an app (ios)

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way by which an app list out the devices that can be connected to my iphone via wi-fi.?
(scanning wi-fi connections that are available)

I tried googling a lot and also checked out some documentation but most of them talked about private APIs.
Any help in this regard would be appreciated.
Is using GameKit an option?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, if you're asking about devices connected to your phone, like keyboards, etc. then that is bluetooth connection, so checking via wifi probably isn't really possible because the devices don't always have wifi in addition to bluetooth.

Comment: @sonu Have you got the solution in listing out all the devices connected with wifi router and also the details of the other devices? Can you please share the solution or code?

Comment: Nope, left it at that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of accessing this information using public APIs. The closest you can get is getting network information using [CaptiveNetwork interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html).